# Connect to Azure Web App via IP address (using App Service Environment)

Tags: azure, ip, app-service-environment

I'm working with azure and (for a specific reason) I need to consume my Azure web app via public IP address (instead a normal url address). I searched around and seems that Web App deployed under a dedicated "**App Service Environment**" can do the trick. Long story short:

1. I deployed my "ASE" resource on Azure (with the related services as you can see from the image below)
   [image]
2. I successfully deployed my web app (well, it's a web socket, but I think it doesn't matter)
3. If I connect via url address (like https://artine.artine.p.azurewebsites.net) it works file (I can "consume" the service)
4. Under IP addresses of my "App Service Environment" I can see my public IP:
   [image]

The problem is that I don't know how to "consume" my API using its IP address. As I can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/app-service/environment/using-an-ase#ip-addresses) the documentation stand:

```
App Service can allocate a dedicated IP address to an app. This capability is available after you configure IP-based SSL
```

---

Is there anyone that can confirm this? So if I "configure IP-based SSL" I can connect to my web API using IP Address (e.g.: https://28.88.887.98?ClientId=AAAAAAAA)

---

Consider that I have no experience on TLS and certificates management. Can you suggest me a good tutorial about configuring "IP-based SSL" on azure? Thank you for your interest

---

**UPDATE:**
Seems that our Azure subscription has some limits so is almost impossible to proceed further finding a solution. At the moment I think I will temporary use a VM (with public IP). Anyway, I really would like to know if someone was able to use a Web API via IP Address. Such information could be handy in the future! Thank you anyway for your interest

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through your question and scenario please be informed that when you deploy your application on Azure you wouldn't be able to use it using IP address because of its architecture where load balancer is in place. Load balancer called as FrontEnd uses the host name and forwards the traffic to that particular worker of your destined app.

**App service architecture:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/february/azure-inside-the-azure-app-service-architecture#front-end

**IP Based SSL** is way of provisioning dedicated IP to your application if you need for any specific whitelisting at any dependency. This IP is provided by Azure platform and to get this IP you just need to select "IP Binding" at the time of securing your domain.

**Conclusion:**
Azure app service cant be consumed only using IP address. It needs host name along with IP to make successful execution.

I hope above clarification and architecture explanation will help you to utilize app service efficiently.